# Access store module action inside plugin

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I am creating a custom backend vee validation. I have installed vee-validate as my plugin. In my vee-validate.js, I am creating an extended validation as below:

```
const isAvailable = async (value) => {
    const response = await axios.post(
        '/api/calls_here',
        { value: value }
    )
    return {
        valid: response.data.valid,
        data: {
            message: response.data.message
        }
    }
}

Validator.extend('available', {
    validate: isAvailable,
    getMessage: (field, params, data) => {
        return data.message
    }
})
```

The thing is, I needed to pass a token for this API call. My token is stored in the store module called "auth". How can I access/import it into my vee-validate.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your token into env variable https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-env/ e.g.

> Example (nuxt.config.js):

```
export default {
  env: {
    myToken: process.env.MYTOKEN || 'http://localhost:3000'
  }
}
```

And then in plugin just use process.env.myToken